# Github branches merging conflict

Tags: git, github, merge, github-for-windows

i have two versions of project, one is constantly updated on Github and other is updating manually, now i want to merge these through Github.

What i did, i created two branches **branch A** and **branch B** from master and in **branch B** i push code that is updating manually and **branch A** has the same code as master.
Now when i create

> New pull request my base is  **branch A**

that is comparing with **branch B**. what this does is take all the changes of **branch B** and remove extra files from **branch A**, but i need those files too.

Kindly correct me if am wrong and also tell me how can i merge those branches so that i can't lost any changes from those branches

Comment: In your **branch B**, did your edits remove those "extra" files from **branch A**? If your manual changes made changes and removed those "extra" files, then you'll need to add them back in.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your desired workflow is here. Could you try explaining in a different way what you mean by updating manually vs same code as master? What is the end goal here, if it was working exactly how you want it to, how would things work?

Comment: @EricLeung do you want me to remove extra files from **branc B** before merging the code?